Service unknown in Symfony
I'm working on Symfony 6.4, and I went to define two LDAP services (one main, one backup).
I have this configuration :
services:
    ...     
    main_ldap_adapter:
      class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter
      arguments:
        - host: '%env(LDAP_SERVER_URL)%'
          port: 389
          options:
            protocol_version: 3
            referrals: false    

    backup_ldap_adapter:
      class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter
      arguments:
        - host: '%env(LDAP_SERVER_BACKUP_URL)%'
          port: 389
          options:
            protocol_version: 3
            referrals: false   
    
    main_ldap:
      class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
      arguments: ['@ldap_adapter']
      tags: ['ldap']

    backup_ldap:
      class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
      arguments: ['@backup_ldap_adapter']
      tags: ['ldap']

    ...

My security.yaml file :
security:
    ...
    providers:
      ldap_main_provider:
        ldap:
          service: main_ldap
          base_dn: '%env(LDAP_BASE_DN)%'
          search_dn: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_DN)%'
          search_password: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_PASSWORD)%'
          default_roles: ROLE_USER
          uid_key: uid
       ldap_backup_provider:
        ldap:
          service: backup_ldap
          base_dn: '%env(LDAP_BASE_DN)%'
          search_dn: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_DN)%'
          search_password: '%env(LDAP_SEARCH_PASSWORD)%'
          default_roles: ROLE_USER
          uid_key: uid
      ...
    firewalls:
        dev:
          pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false
        login:
          pattern: ^/api/login
          provider: ldap_main_provider
          form_login_ldap:
            login_path: api_login
            check_path: api_login
            username_parameter: login
            password_parameter: password
            service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
            dn_string: '%env(LDAP_DN_STRING)%'
            success_handler: App\Security\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
            failure_handler: App\Security\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandler
     ...

When I try to connect, I have this error : "Cannot check credentials using the "Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap" ldap service, as such service is not found. Did you maybe forget to add the "ldap" service tag to this service?"
Do you know why ?
When I've only one service defined this way :
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap:
      arguments: ['@ldap_adapter']
      tags: ['ldap']

and I use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap in my security.providers.ldap_main_provider.ldap.service, it's working...
Do you know what I can do please ?
Thanks !
I see my services in php bin/console debug:container | grep ldap

Try changing firewalls.login.form_login_ldap.service with main_ldap you are setting it to Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap which is not defined in your services, that's probably why you are getting the error message

Perfect, thanks ! My goal is to have chained providers, in order to try to authenticate the users on the backup if the main ldap is down. Do you please know how to proceed for the firewalls.login.form_login_ldap.service key ?
I add in my providers ldaps.chain.providers: [ldap_main_provider, ldap_backup_provider] but I really don't know how to proceed for the rest (I also add the chain name ldaps in my firewalls.login.provider)

try removing firewalls.login.form_login_ldap.service as it will default to ldap and putting instead firewalls.login.form_login_ldap.provider with ldaps note that provideris under form_login_ldap not login

Thanks ! However, I already tried and I have this error : Cannot check credentials using the "ldap" ldap service, as such service is not found. Did you maybe forget to add the "ldap" service tag to this service?
